# Is there a way to check all the components name in java using a loop?

Tags: java

the reason im asking this is because for example I have 3 textbox name(variable), text_1,text_2 and text_3. and i want to automatically write something in the textbox depending on which textbox name(variable) i have to write on. Using a loop I need to check if current textbox name is text_1, text_2 or text_3.

if i were to write it in pseudo code it will look like this:

```
loop:
     if(component name == text_1)
        text_1.setText = text;
     else if(component name == text_2)
     .... and so on..
```

Comment: Have you considered putting all these names in an array or a collection of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what arrays are for. Then you can access them by index with

```
textFields[0].setText(text);
```

and doing something to all of them is just a matter of using a loop and an index.